# SQL, combining the result

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Access and have this SQL

```
SELECT land.id, land.official_name, vaksiner.vaksiner
FROM land INNER JOIN (vaksiner INNER JOIN land_sykdom ON vaksiner.id = land_sykdom.sykdom)        ON land.kort = land_sykdom.land
ORDER BY land.official_name
```

The SQL gives me a result like this:

```
id    official_name    vaksiner

1     a                A
1     a                C    
2     b                A
2     b                B
2     b                C
```

But I want to combine the result so that it looks like this:

```
id    official_name    vaksiner

1     a                A, C
2     b                A, B, C
```

Comment: I haven't downloaded this but it looks like it may do what you need? http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/forum/generic-function-to-concatenate-child-records_topic16.html

Comment: If you're using VBA or some other interface language, it's probably easier to do this in a procedural language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Allen Browne's ConcatRelated function ([Concatenate values from related records](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html))

If you save your existing query as *qryVaksinerRaw*, you can build a new query like this to produce the results you're after.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id,
    official_name,
    ConcatRelated("vaksiner","qryVaksinerRaw","id = " & [id]) AS vaksiner
FROM qryVaksinerRaw;
```

To add the function to a module, copy the function from the web page starting with

```
Public Function ConcatRelated(strField As String, _
```

and continuing to include

```
End Function
```

Then paste the copied text into your module.

Note `ConcatRelated()` will then be available for queries run from inside Access.  However, like any custom VBA function, it can not be used in queries run from outside Access (like classic ASP, .Net, etc.)

Comment: I tried it but I could not make it work. How do you add it to Access? What function should I paste into the module (referring to the 3rd step on "How to use the function http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html )?