# Implementing a "special" Access database to Expression Web

Tags: sql, ms-access, expression-web

I have just got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032719/sql-combining-the-result) to my question about combining the result of a SQL. This was done with "ConcatRelated". Now I want to implement this in Expression Web 3.

The SQL's I used in Access:

```
SELECT land.id, land.official_name, vaksiner.vaksiner
FROM land INNER JOIN (vaksiner INNER JOIN land_sykdom ON vaksiner.id = land_sykdom.sykdom) ON land.kort = land_sykdom.land
ORDER BY land.official_name;
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, official_name, ConcatRelated("vaksiner","qryVaksinerRaw","id = " &    [id]) AS vaksiner
FROM qryVaksinerRaw;
```

The last is saved as vaksine_query

This is the SQL that I want to add to Expression Web:

```
SELECT vaksine_query.id, vaksine_query.official_name, vaksine_query.vaksiner
FROM vaksine_query
WHERE vaksine_query.id="?";
```

Expression Web gives me the error message "Undefined function 'ContactRelated' in expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in ConcatRelated is a User Defined Function, and it will not work outside Access.

It seems likely that you will have to get your recordset and then loop through it to build the concatenated output.