# CONCAT in SQL ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this two tables:

```
TABLE_1
CODE    TYPE
A100    A
A100    B
A100    C
A200    A
A200    A

TABLE_2
CODE    DESCRIPTION
A100    XY
A200    ZH
```

I would like to join the two tables with the following result:

```
CODE    DESCRIPTION TYPECONCAT
A100       XY        A, B, C
A200       ZH           A
```

The first column contains the unique code, the second column contains a generic description and the third one concatenates the different types of the first table. 
I tried with the following code:

```
SELECT Distinct
Code,
Type,
Concat ("TypeConcat", “my_table”, "Code=""" & [Code] & """ and Type=""" & [Type] & """") AS TypeConcat
FROM my_table;
```

I don’t know how to concatenate, using & operator in this case.

Thank you!

Comment: Since Access SQL does not include a `Concat()` function, consider Allen Browne's [ConcatRelated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3032853/77335) function.

Comment: @HansUp I tried to do it like it is described in the link, but Access gives an error: Undifined function "ConcatRelated" in expression. WHat could be the reason?

Comment: Are you running your query from within an Access application session?  A custom VBA function can not be used in a query run from outside an Access session --- say if you're running the query from a .Net application, classic ASP, Java, Python, etc.

Comment: @HansUp i'm trying to run query from Access

Comment: If the module where you saved that function is also named *ConcatRelated*, Access may be confused.  If that is the case, rename the module to *modConcatRelated* and try again.

Comment: @HansUp Yes, that helped, that error does not occur anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Couple of combined techniques here, the CONCAT doesn't do quite what your looking for, but this will.

```
SELECT 'A100' AS [CODE], 'A' AS [TYPE] INTO #TABLE_1
INSERT into #TABLE_1 VALUES('A100','B')
INSERT into #TABLE_1 VALUES('A100','C')
INSERT into #TABLE_1 VALUES('A200','A')
INSERT into #TABLE_1 VALUES('A200','A')

SELECT 'A100' AS [CODE], 'XY' AS [DESCRIPTION] INTO #TABLE_2
INSERT into #TABLE_2 VALUES('A200','ZH')

SELECT DISTINCT t1.[CODE], t2.[DESCRIPTION], 
    (   SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT CAST(', ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + [Type]
            FROM #TABLE_1 t3
            WHERE t1.[CODE] = t3.[CODE]

            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,2,'') 
    ) AS [TYPECONCAT]
FROM    #TABLE_1 t1
JOIN    #TABLE_2 t2 ON t1.[CODE] = t2.[CODE]

DROP TABLE #TABLE_1
DROP TABLE #TABLE_2
```

Main useful bit is the FOR XML PATH command, worth playing with.

Credit should also go to codemonkeycaffeine, for the basic technique that I utilised.

https://codemonkeycaffeine.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/sql-joining-rows-into-a-single-field/

Comment: `STUFF`, `CAST`, and `FOR XML PATH` are not supported in Access SQL.

Comment: Gotcha - This is a SQL Server answer not specific to access. Hopefully may help someone out though.