# Trying to combine results of Access query in new field

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an Access database that tracks bid numbers in one table and the person/persons working on the bid via a one to many relation linked to the ID field in another table. What I am trying to do is consolidate the results when there are multiple people working on a bid so that the results can be bound to a report field. Not having much luck in scouring the internet. Small example below.

Typical result:

```
Table 1 Table 2 Table 2
BidID   BidID   Quoter
100         100  RAR
101         101  RAR
101         101  ABC
101         101  HIJ
102         102  ABC
103         103  RAR
103         103  ABC
```

Result I want:

```
Table 1 Table 2 Generated result
BidID   BidID   Combined Field
100         100  RAR
101         101  RAR, ABC, HIJ
102         102  ABC
103         103  RAR, ABC
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Ron

Comment: See whether [ConcatRelated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3032853/77335) will do what you need.

Comment: That worked great. Thank you.